# How to pass stream from Naudio to MS SpeechRecognization?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, naudio, sapi

I am trying to use SetInputToAudioStream method for speech engine.

But it does not work. 
I've also searched few articles and tried every possible way. but it still does not work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203533/1336662

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203533/1336662

I had to use the SpeechStreamer class described in [Sean's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11813276/1336662) in order for the SpeechRecognitionEngine to work.

Here is my code, please if anyone can help me, that will be great.

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.AudioFormat;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;

namespace WpfAppNAudio
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            console.AppendText("Click to start recording");
        }
        public WaveIn waveSource = null;
        public WaveFileWriter waveFile = null;
        private SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = null;
        //Stream a = null;
        SpeechStreamer stream = null;
        private bool _recognizing;

        void RecognizeSpeechAndWriteToConsole()
        {
            _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            try
            {
                //_recognizer.
                // Create and load a grammar.  
                Grammar dictation = new DictationGrammar();
                dictation.Name = "Dictation Grammar";

                _recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictation);


                _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += _recognizer_SpeechRecognized; // if speech is recognized, call the specified method
                _recognizer.SpeechRecognitionRejected += _recognizer_SpeechRecognitionRejected; // if recognized speech is rejected, call the specified method
                _recognizer.SpeechDetected += _recognizer_SpeechDetected;
                _recognizer.RecognizeCompleted += _recognizer_RecognizeCompleted;


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        private void _recognizer_RecognizeCompleted(object sender, RecognizeCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void _recognizer_SpeechDetected(object sender, SpeechDetectedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void _recognizer_SpeechRecognitionRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            console.AppendText("speech rejected");
        }

        private void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            console.AppendText("speech recognized" + e.Result.Text);
        }

        private void StartBtn_Click()
        {

            waveSource = new WaveIn();
            waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(22050, 8, 1);

            waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
            waveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveSource_RecordingStopped);

            waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(@"C:\Temp\Test0001.wav", waveSource.WaveFormat);

            console.AppendText("Starting recording");
            RecognizeSpeechAndWriteToConsole();
            waveSource.StartRecording();

        }

        void StopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            waveSource.StopRecording();
        }

        void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveFile != null)
            {
                stream = new SpeechStreamer(e.Buffer.Length);               
                stream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
                waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
                waveFile.Flush();
                if (!_recognizing)
                {
                    _recognizing = true;
                    _recognizer.SetInputToAudioStream(stream, new System.Speech.AudioFormat.SpeechAudioFormatInfo(22050, System.Speech.AudioFormat.AudioBitsPerSample.Eight, System.Speech.AudioFormat.AudioChannel.Mono));
                    var s = _recognizer.RecognizerInfo.SupportedAudioFormats;
                    _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                }
            }
        }

        void waveSource_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveSource != null)
            {
                waveSource.Dispose();
                waveSource = null;
            }

            if (waveFile != null)
            {
                waveFile.Dispose();
                waveFile = null;
            }

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StartBtn_Click();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            waveSource.StopRecording();
        }
    }

    class SpeechStreamer : Stream
    {
        private AutoResetEvent _writeEvent;
        private List<byte> _buffer;
        private int _buffersize;
        private int _readposition;
        private int _writeposition;
        private bool _reset;

        public SpeechStreamer(int bufferSize)
        {
            _writeEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            _buffersize = bufferSize;
            _buffer = new List<byte>(_buffersize);
            for (int i = 0; i < _buffersize; i++)
                _buffer.Add(new byte());
            _readposition = 0;
            _writeposition = 0;
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override bool CanSeek
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override long Length
        {
            get { return -1L; }
        }

        public override long Position
        {
            get { return 0L; }
            set { }
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            return 0L;
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {

        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < count && _writeEvent != null)
            {
                if (!_reset && _readposition >= _writeposition)
                {
                    _writeEvent.WaitOne(100, true);
                    continue;
                }
                buffer[i] = _buffer[_readposition + offset];
                _readposition++;
                if (_readposition == _buffersize)
                {
                    _readposition = 0;
                    _reset = false;
                }
                i++;
            }

            return count;
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            for (int i = offset; i < offset + count; i++)
            {
                _buffer[_writeposition] = buffer[i];
                _writeposition++;
                if (_writeposition == _buffersize)
                {
                    _writeposition = 0;
                    _reset = true;
                }
            }
            _writeEvent.Set();

        }

        public override void Close()
        {
            _writeEvent.Close();
            _writeEvent = null;
            base.Close();
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            stream = new SpeechStreamer(e.Buffer.Length);               
            stream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
```

Is this really the only place that is writing to the stream, no where else in the application? If it only writes some bytes when it initializes it will not continue to get audio coming in to the recognizer.